# parsing a C++ type constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class Vec
{
   public:

   typedef T* iterator;
   typedef const T* const_iterator;
   typedef size_t size_type;
   typedef T value_type;


   explicit Vec(size_t n, const T & val = T());

   private:
   iterator data;
   iterator avail;
   iterator limit;

}

template <typename T>

Vec<T>::Vec<T>(size_t n, const T & val)
: data(new T[n]), avail(data + n), limit(data + n)
{
   for (iterator p = data; p != avail; ++p)
   *p = val;
}
```

I have some trouble understanding what's being done here.

Ok, so we have a constructor for a Vector containing an object T. We pass the size of size_type, which contains a number and the value_type T, whose constructor is called inside the parameter field. Then the constructor of vector creates an object data. Now, I don't understand what the type of the object data is, and I don't know why it's calling a constructor that wasn't defined anywhere, I am not quite sure what's being done here, because I don't use that syntax when I define a constructor, then the other thing is I don't know what avail and limit is and why we are using the operator on a object of type size_type and another object of a different type (is data, avail and limit arrays of T?).

Comment: `data`, `avail`, and `limit` should be members of the class. Judging from the use, `data` is a pointer to the beginning, and the other two are pointers to one beyond the last element and the end of the allocated block.

Comment: The code is incomplete.  We have no way of knowing the answers to your questions (although we could guess). Where did you see it? Surely there was more to it than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Vec` class would have other members that you didn't show:

```
T *data;
T *avail;
T *limit;
```

You seem to not realize that these variables exist; but you could find them by looking in the same place that you found the rest of the definition of `Vec` that you posted.

The syntax for constructor initializers (the stuff after the `:`) is a list of `name(value)`.

The difference between these two:

```
Foo::Foo(string x): member_var(x) {}

Foo::Foo(string x) { member_var = x; }
```

is that in the first one, `x` is supplied directly to the constructor of `data`. In the second one, `data` is constructed first using its default constructor, and then its assignment operator is called. This is a logically different series of events;  and if you have a class that doesn't have a default constructor then the second one isn't even possible.

If you don't use this constructor syntax then you should start using it.

In your example, `data` is initialized to some freshly-allocated memory; and the pointers `avail` and `limit` are both set to point to the end of this allocated block.

Presumably `limit` indicates the end of allocated storage, and `avail` indicates the end of objects actually in the vector.  Perhaps it would have been simpler to make these `size_t` containing an object count, instead of a pointer, but the two approaches are equivalent.

> why we are using the operator on a object of type size_type

I'm not sure what you are trying to say here. The type of `n` is `size_t` (not "size_type"), this is a built-in type to C++ that is able to hold the maximum size of an object. The typedef `Vec::size_type` is so that people who are using a `Vec` know what data type to use to hold indices into this vector.

The code inside the constructor body loops through the vector and copies the initial value to each member.

Comment: Are we assigning an array to data? new T[n] should create an array.

Comment: A pointer to a dynamically allocated array, `new T[n]`. And it's initialization, not assignment.

Comment: btw data, limit and avail are iterators

Comment: Well, `iterator` is a typedef for `T*` .  Conceptually they should actually be `T*` because that's what they are; and the class could have a more complicated `iterator`.

Comment: so ptr = new T[n] points to the first element of T[n]? and thus because ptr contains the address (ex:194384) when we add n we get the initial address + n (ex:194384+n or 193485 if n = 1)?

Comment: The `new` expression returns a pointer to the first element of the allocated storage. The way that pointer arithmetic works is that if `p` is pointing to the `x`'th element, then `p + y` points to the `x + y`'th element.

Comment: @user3435009 Their names don't suggest that they are iterators, and you're not initializing them accordingly if they are. Iterators aren't members of a class in any case, they are dynamically created objects that you return on demand. In fact they aren't anything until you declare them. You didn't. Matt did. You don't have any basis for arguing about it.

Comment: so, without new it wouldn't return the pointer to the first element?

Comment: @EJP `T*` is a suitable iterator type for a contiguous array. He means that they are declared as `iterator avail;` etc.

Comment: @OP, without `new` there would be no storage allocated . The memory allocated by this `new` is where the objects held in this `Vec` are stored.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not interested in guessing what he means. If they have declarations, he should have posted them. With those names and as class members they can't be iterators, whatever he may intend.

Comment: @EJP Bet you five bucks they're declared as `iterator avail;` etc. , and if so, they then can be iterators, i.e. things that iterate.